# Memoir: Change dots in ToC to colored horizontal line

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

Using memoir, I want to change the ToC such that it displays a **colored** horizontal line (`_____`) instead of the dots between the chapter name and the page number. Is this possible?

Before:

```
1 First Chapter . . . . . . . 5
```

After:

```
1 First Chapter _____________ 5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\color{green}\hrulefill}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\color{green}\hrulefill}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Change `green` to the color you like.

Comment: Thank you. I added additional spaces `\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\color{green}~\hrulefill~}`